# Moving cells between cells in excel using python

Tags: python, excel-automation

I need to move cell D3 to D4  in excel if cell A3 is not equal to C3 can anyone tell how to do this using python?

Comment: use pandas. can you share the excel file/data set?

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you asked for:

```py
import openpyxl

filename = 'table.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active

if ws['A3'] != ws['C3']:
    ws['D4'] = ws['D3'].value
    ws['D3'] = None

wb.save(filename)
```

Make sure not to have the file open in Excel while you do this, or you'll get permission errors. If you want to do this dynamically (while you have the file open) you'll have to use `pywin32` which is slightly more challenging.